# Correctly save list to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using the `Selenium` library, I get some information (a table from the site) and try to save this table to a `CSV file`.

```
elements_xpach_url = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/span[2]/table/tbody[2]')
values = re.split('\n', elements_xpach_url.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df.to_csv('csv.csv', index=False, header=False, sep=';')
```

In the final file, there is no way to set the division as a `semicolon` `;` instead of a `space`.
[image]

```
    print(type(values))
    print(values)
```

[image]

Could you tell me please, how can this be implemented? Thank you very much!

Comment: `sep` is the correct parameter, if you have issues, the spaces/tabs are likely already there in the data. Please provide a reproducible example as your issue likely happens before exporting

Comment: @mozway, Updated my question. You're right, there is already a space character in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data, you likely want to split your strings on spaces:

```
values = [re.split() for x in re.split('\n', elements_xpach_url.text)]
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

Note that you do not need `re.split` to split on newlines, `str.split` is enough:

```
values = [re.split() for x in elements_xpach_url.text.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```